# Python Pandas Split/Trim remove a character at the end of a column of string with .endswith()?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in Pandas that removes the last character for each cell using the endswith() method?

Sample Dataframe:

| Index | Sentences |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | This is a sentence |
| 02 | This is a sentence. |
| 03 | This is also a sentence |
| 04 | This is also a sentence. |

I need to remove the period at the end because Pandas does not recognize that 1&2 and 3&4 are duplicates because of the period ('.') that exists.

Comment: please provide a full sample, input, output, what you tried so far. And yes this sounds like it can be achived, but propably not with enndswith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the last period `.` at the end, you can use [`.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace the period at the end (indicated by a `$` which is the regex meta-character for end of line anchor.

```
df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].str.replace(r'\.$', '', regex=True)
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`str.rstrip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html), as follows:

```
df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].str.rstrip('.')
```

Or, [`str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with the $ anchor, as follows:

```
df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].str.strip(r'\.$')
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   Index                Sentences
0      1       This is a sentence
1      2       This is a sentence
2      3  This is also a sentence
3      4  This is also a sentence
```

Comment: This won't affect periods at the middle of the sentence because of the $ sign right?

Comment: @KenRusselSy  Yes, that's right.  Won't affect the period in the middle.

Comment: @KenRusselSy  Added explanation of the $ anchor.  Also added another solution.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without turning the Dataframe to a Series?

Comment: @KenRusselSy  We are modifying just one Series of the Dataframe.  We don't change the structure of the overall Dataframe and will not change the Dataframe `df` into a Series.  So, any problem you face ?

Answer (score 1):

> string.rstrip(s[, chars]) Return a copy of the string with trailing
> characters removed. If chars is omitted or None, whitespace characters
> are removed. If given and not None, chars must be a string; the
> characters in the string will be stripped from the end of the string
> this method is called on.

```
df['Sentences'].str.rstrip('.')
```

it should work

Comment: `df['Sentences']` is a Pandas `Series`, not a string, so the docs on python strings are not directly useful here as pandas Series do not have an `rstrip` attribute.

Comment: I updated , just get str from df['Sentences']

Comment: Don't forget to update the docs to reflect `Series.str.rstrip` instead of `python.string.rstrip`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use str.replace with regex .txt$'

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 2, 1: 1}, 
                   'C': {0: 5, 1: 1}, 
                   'B': {0: 4, 1: 2}, 
                   'filename': {0: "txt.txt", 1: "x.txt"}}, 
                columns=['filename','A','B', 'C'])

print df
  filename  A  B  C
0  txt.txt  2  4  5
1    x.txt  1  2  1

df['filename'] = df['filename'].str.replace(r'.txt$', '')
print df
  filename  A  B  C
0      txt  2  4  5
1        x  1  2  1

df['filename'] = df['filename'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-4])
print df
  filename  A  B  C
0      txt  2  4  5
1        x  1  2  1

df['filename'] = df['filename'].str[:-4]
print df
  filename  A  B  C
0      txt  2  4  5
1        x  1  2  1
```

rstrip can remove more characters, if the end of strings contains some characters of striped string (in this case ., t, x):

Comment: I'll give that a try